# Android LinkMovementMethod in XML?

Tags: android, linkify

To enable `Linkify` behavior, I do this in code:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Is there a way to set this in the layout `xml` for the `textview`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is not. If you are using `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` in so many places in your app that you want to avoid it, you should consider creating and using a custom class extending `TextView` which executes that method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "autoLink" property in the XML layout

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin you can create an extension function like this

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
fun TextView.makeHyperLink(url: String) {
    text = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Html.fromHtml("<a href='${url}'>${text}</a>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    } else {
        Html.fromHtml("<a href='${url}'>${text}</a>")
    }
    movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    isClickable = true
}
```